# How do I regulate the level of UIVisualEffectView blur

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a UIVisualEffectView to make a nice blur effect in my view. But I think that the UIVisualEffectView generates a very strong blur.

I'm trying to regulate a level of blur to my UIVisualEffectView, I want a weak blur.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use UIImage+ImageEffects.h category from WWDC 2013. It has more stuff to tune

e.g. from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/tree/master/Anypic-iOS/Vendor/UIImageEffects

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with a `UIVisualEffectView` - the only options for blur are:

```
enum UIBlurEffectStyle : Int {
    case ExtraLight
    case Light
    case Dark
}
```

There's no property on [`UIBlurEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBlurEffect), [`UIVisualEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVisualEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIVisualEffect), or [`UIVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIVisualEffectView/contentView) for 'magnitude' of the blur.

[This blog post](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/01/blur-effect-in-ios-applications/?lang=en) is a good place to start if you want to 'roll your own' blur view with a custom magnitude.